# Azure Push Notification not open my app ¿?

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

I have a Xamarin Forms App and when I receive a notification, If I click on it, from an android device, I open the app without any problem, but If I do the same with iOS, I receive the notification, with my text and my title, but when I click the notification, suddenly it try to open the app, but the app finally crash

Can anyone help me??

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: I don't know exactly, because I test the app with Diawi, and I can't see the exception

Comment: Are you using template notifications, or are you passing the same notification body to both an iOS and Android app? While both platforms expect JSON, the expected layout is quite different. If you're passing the same body, the app is likely crashing when the iOS app doesn't get the "aps" property that it was expecting.